# ON Clause to Correctly Join these two tables?

Tags: mysql, database

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdnWF.png)

First one gives all possible combinations

```
SELECT Album.title, Artist.name FROM Album JOIN Artist 

SELECT Album.title, Artist.name FROM Track JOIN Album JOIN Artist ON Track.artist_id =
```

I want that the The correct Album should get displayed along with the correct artist name. Is it possible or I need to setup relationship between Album and Artist tables.

Comment: Hi. No pictures, thanks. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify a join condition for the first join, too:

```
SELECT Album.title, Artist.name, Track.title 
FROM Track 
JOIN Album ON(Track.album_id = Album.album_id) 
JOIN Artist ON(Track.artist_id = Artist.artist_id)
```

You should provide indexes and foreign key constraints on your database tables, but it will work without, even if slowly or without data integrity.